# Google Drive, hide "D:/" volume

Tags: google-drive

I just downloaded `Drive for Desktop` that replaces the old `backup and sync` application. Now I have an ugly `Google Drive (D:)` that shows up under Devices and drives, in My Computer (This PC). It doesn't show under Disk Management. How am I supposed to remove or hide this? Searching in google shows no relevant results because the search terms are ambiguous.

[image]

Comment: Try the method described in [this post](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/48991-add-remove-google-drive-navigation-pane-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: @harrymc I am pretty sure this is different. The navigation panel shortcuts can be edited by modifying the registry. But this is a virtual drive. And it doesn't show up on Disk Management.

Answer (score 3):

- Click the google drive icon on the right taskbar, click the setting icon (gear), then preferences
- Google Drive preferences window will show, click the setting icon again on the top right one
- Change google drive streaming location from "Drive Letter" to "Folder"
- Save, and restart windows explorer

[image]

Comment: I'm really glad that this option has finally been added.  I'm surprised that this post (as of this moment) has less than a thousand views, because for years, so many people were complaining about having an extra drive letter added to their computer.